# How to set up Dell ControlVault w/ Fingerprint Touch Sensor under 16.04?

Tags: dell, fingerprint-reader

I have a Dell Latitude E5470 with the above mentioned fingerprint sensor. When I started Ubuntu in live mode I had an option at the user account screen called "fingerprint login" (like [this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-belYrEP0TOY/T64Q45L3aEI/AAAAAAAAN-o/m7Rxg68_55Q/s1600/User+Accounts_060.png)) but after install this option gone.

[lspci and lsusb](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23123527/)

The device with the ID 0a5c:5834 refers to the fingerprint reader.

How can I set up my fingerprint reader?
In case you need some additional logs please let me know.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Did you eventually find a fix?

Comment: @MihaiStancu No, unfortunately I did not :(

Comment: I don't have the "fingerprint disabled" there in the "Users & Groups" settings menu.

Comment: Hmm I in the boot-disk I can see it. Make me wonder... I moved my install from a laptop to another.

Comment: @MihaiStancu Were you able to reach any further progress in that case? :)

Comment: Nope. I researched the official Dell support based on the driver code and similar codes. I also researched 3 opensource projects which have lists of driver codes they support and neither has our driver..

Comment: @MihaiStancu That's so sad. Maybe 16.10 willl fix the issue, I hope so. Thanks.

Comment: Since it's a driver thing it's not necessarily likely. Also since it's not a core functionality it's also not much incentive for devs to make it work.